# The preserved tablet is it beneath the throne or above the throne?

Tags: quran, hadith-interpretation

Nowhere in the Quran Allah said that with him is the preserved tablet above the throne rather it is very illogical to say that with Allah is the preserved tablet which is a creation of Allah above his throne while throne is the roof of every living thing which is created from water and Allah is the Most High, so this hadith is very confusing! Please help me to understand this hadith.

Narrated Abu Huraira: The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "When Allah created the Creation, He wrote in His Book--and He wrote (that) about Himself, and it is placed with Him on the Throne--'Verily My Mercy overcomes My Anger.'" : Sahih al-Bukhari 7404

Comment: I don't quite get what the problem is. What is wrong with the book being above the Throne?